# MongoDB java API - I can't figure out why MongoDB Java API does not returns correct result for a particular date range criteria?

Tags: java, mongodb

Following function fetches data from mongoDB between range `fromDate` and `toDate` and some  `andCriteria`. I am facing a weird issue. If both `fromDate` and `toDate` are from same year, say `10/23/2017` to `12/31/2017` the method correctly returns the result. But if year is different, say date range is `12/24/2017` to `01/04/2018` it does not return anything. It works fine even for date range like `01/01/2018` to `01/08/2018`. Date is in **mm/dd/yyyy** format.

```
public List<DataCompanyVO> filterByAndCriteriaWithDateRange(String fromDate, String toDate, Map<String, String> andCriteria) {

    List<DataCompanyVO> dataCompanyList = new ArrayList<DataCompanyVO>();

    if (andCriteria == null || andCriteria.isEmpty() || StringUtils.isBlank(fromDate) || StringUtils.isBlank(toDate)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Arguments");
    }
    String dateFilter = FilterType.RUN_DATE.value();
    try {

        MongoCollection<Document> dataCompanyCollection = getMongoDatabase().getCollection(DATA_COMPANY_COLLECTION);
        List<Bson> bsonList = new ArrayList<Bson>();

        // add bson for eq comparison
        for (String criteria : andCriteria.keySet()) {
            bsonList.add(eq(criteria, andCriteria.get(criteria)));
        }

        if (fromDate.equals(toDate)) {
            bsonList.add(eq(dateFilter, fromDate));
        } else {
            bsonList.add(gte(dateFilter, fromDate));
            bsonList.add(lte(dateFilter, toDate));
        }

        FindIterable<Document> docIterable = dataCompanyCollection.find(and(bsonList));

        MongoCursor<Document> iterator = docIterable.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Document doc = iterator.next();
            dataCompanyList.add(wrapIntoModel(doc));
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("message", e);
    }

    return dataCompanyList;
```

Comment: When you use string dates you perform lexicographical comparison where 01 comes before 12. You need to save the dates in date type or in iso string format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Here is equivalent mongo query                                       `{ date: {$gte: "10/16/2017"}, date: {$lte: "01/08/2018"}, field1: "field1_Val", field2: "field2_Val" }` . This is working just fine. Also the date is stored as string in the db. This is causing issue only through  mongo Java API

Comment: No these are two different queries. Try the  equalivent  query  is `{date: {$gte: "10/16/2017", $lte: "01/08/2018"}}`. It shouldn't not return any results.What you are doing is overwriting keys lte query criteria overwrites gte query criteria in the shell query.